# How to make a decoder with an optional element?

Tags: elm, decoder

I’m stuck with a decoder that should decode an array `[ 9.34958, 48.87733, 1000 ]` to a `Point`, where index 2 (elevation) is optional.

```
type alias Point =
    { elev : Maybe Float
    , at : Float
    , lng : Float
    }
```

Therefore I created following decoder:

```
fromArrayDecoder : Decoder Point
fromArrayDecoder =
    map3 Point
        (index 2 Decode.float |> Decode.maybe)
        (index 1 Decode.float)
        (index 0 Decode.float)
```

My problem now is, that this decoder succeeds when index 2 is missing or is of any type like string etc. But I want it only to succeed if elev is missing, not if it has the wrong type. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "missing"? Is it `null`, or does the array just have two elements in that case?

Answer (score 5):

If by "missing" you mean the value can be `null`, you can just use [`nullable`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#nullable) instead of `maybe`:

```
fromArrayDecoder : Decoder Point
fromArrayDecoder =
  map3 Point
    (index 2 Decode.float |> Decode.nullable)
    (index 1 Decode.float)
    (index 0 Decode.float)
```

If it's either a 3-element array or a two-element array you can use [`oneOf`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#oneOf) to try several decoders in order:

```
fromTwoArrayDecoder : Decoder Point
fromTwoArrayDecoder =
  map3 (Point Nothing)
    (index 1 Decode.float)
    (index 0 Decode.float)

fromThreeArrayDecoder : Decoder Point
fromThreeArrayDecoder =
  map3 Point
    (index 2 Decode.float |> Decode.map Just)
    (index 1 Decode.float)
    (index 0 Decode.float)

fromArrayDecoder : Decoder Point
fromArrayDecoder =
  oneOf
    [ fromThreeArrayDecoder
    , fromTwoArrayDecoder
    ]
```

Just remember to try the 3-element decoder first, as the 2-element decoder will succeed on a 3-element array as well, but the opposite does not.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the fact `Json.Decode.maybe` giving you `Nothing` on a *wrong* value rather than just a *missing* one is surprising.

[`elm-json-decode-pipeline`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline/latest) can work in the way you want without getting too verbose.

```
> d = Decode.succeed Point 
|   |> optional "2" (Decode.float |> Decode.map Just) Nothing 
|   |> required "1" Decode.float 
|   |> required "0" Decode.float
|
> "[1, 2, \"3\"]" |> Decode.decodeString d
Err (Failure ("Json.Decode.oneOf failed in the following 2 ways:\n\n\n\n(1) Problem with the given value:\n    \n    \"3\"\n    \n    Expecting a FLOAT\n\n\n\n(2) Problem with the given value:\n    \n    \"3\"\n    \n    Expecting null") <internals>)
    : Result Decode.Error Point
> "[1, 2, 3]" |> Decode.decodeString d
Ok { at = 2, elev = Just 3, lng = 1 }
    : Result Decode.Error Point
> "[1, 2]" |> Decode.decodeString d
Ok { at = 2, elev = Nothing, lng = 1 }
    : Result Decode.Error Point
```

(You can see from the error that under the hood it is using `oneOf` like [in glennsl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60082459/722121).)

The only potentially surprising thing here is that you need to pass strings rather than int indexes, as there isn't a specific version for lists but you can access list indexes as though they are field names. This does mean that this version is subtly different in that it will *not* throw an error if you can an object with number field names rather than an array, but I can't imagine that really being an issue. The more real issue is it could make your error messages less accurate:

```
> "[0]" |> Decode.decodeString (Decode.field "0" Decode.int)
Ok 0 : Result Decode.Error Int
> "[]" |> Decode.decodeString (Decode.field "0" Decode.int)
Err (Failure ("Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `0`") <internals>)
    : Result Decode.Error Int
> "[]" |> Decode.decodeString (Decode.index 0 Decode.int)
Err (Failure ("Expecting a LONGER array. Need index 0 but only see 0 entries") <internals>)
```

Note that you do still have to to avoid using `Json.Decode.maybe`. It may be tempting to write `optional "2" (Decode.maybe Decode.float) Nothing` which will result in the same behaviour as you originally got.